# Can't add a prefix on values based on a condition in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

First of all, I am new to Python so I am not an expert...

Here's my issue. I have this dataframe:

```
   CODE_IRIS  PDL_RESIDENTIEL  PDL_TOTAL  CONSO_RESIDENTIEL  CONSO_TOTALE
0  10040101               500        510              11264         26677
1  10040102               806        809              16234         17318
2  10040201               921        925              14451         17065
3  10040202               937        943              13036         19516
4  10049999                94         94               1287          1287
```

The thing is, `CODE_IRIS` is an `object` and is supposed to have 9 characters, like this :

```
       CODE_IRIS  PDL_RESIDENTIEL  PDL_TOTAL  CONSO_RESIDENTIEL  CONSO_TOTALE
17861  766810113              588        593               9344         14743
```

Therefore, I need to pass a prefix `0` when the length of characters in `CODE_IRIS` is inferior to 9, like I would do on Excel with the formula `=IF(LEN([@[Code IRIS]]) < 9; 0&[@[Code IRIS]]; [@[Code IRIS]])`.

Now, when I try to locate what are the values with only 8 characters with `elec.loc[elec['CODE_IRIS'].str.len() < 9]`, the result I get is:

```
Out[393]: 
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [CODE_IRIS, PDL_RESIDENTIEL, PDL_TOTAL, CONSO_RESIDENTIEL, CONSO_TOTALE]
Index: []
```

Then when I try to see how long each value is with `elec['CODE_IRIS'].str.len()`, the result I get is:

```
Out[396]: 
0       NaN
1       NaN
...
Name: CODE_IRIS, Length: 23905, dtype: float64
```

Although the column `CODE_IRIS` is definitely an `object`, as you can see here:

```
elec.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 23905 entries, 0 to 23904
Data columns (total 5 columns):
CODE_IRIS            23905 non-null object
PDL_RESIDENTIEL      23905 non-null int64
PDL_TOTAL            23905 non-null int64
CONSO_RESIDENTIEL    23905 non-null int64
CONSO_TOTALE         23905 non-null int64
dtypes: int64(4), object(1)
memory usage: 1.1+ MB
```

I don't understand. Can someone explain me what's wrong?

(I hope I have made myself as understandable as possible).
thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use [`zfill`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.zfill) on every `CODE_IRIS`:

```
df['CODE_IRIS'] = df['CODE_IRIS'].map(lambda x: str(x).zfill(9))
```